# Error at the end when compiling android (crdroid)

Tags: android, build

Compiled crdroid, device cereus android 11. At the very end of the compilation an error popped up:

The beginning of the error (the rest is not interesting)

```
FAILED: out/target/product/cereus/lineage_cereus-ota-eng.alexander.zip out/target/product/cereus/ota_metadata
/bin/bash -c "PATH=out/host/linux-x86/bin/:system/extras/ext4_utils/:\$PATH out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files --verbose --extracted_input_target_files out/target/product/cereus/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_cereus-target_files-eng.alexander --path out/host/linux-x86 --backup=true  -k build/make/target/product/security/testkey --output_metadata_path out/target/product/cereus/ota_metadata out/target/product/cereus/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_cereus-target_files-eng.alexander.zip out/target/product/cereus/lineage_cereus-ota-eng.alexander.zip"
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM/etc/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/etc/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read VENDOR/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/etc/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read PRODUCT/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/etc/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read SYSTEM_EXT/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read ODM/etc/build.prop
2022-01-22 19:44:39 - common.py - WARNING : Failed to read ODM/build.prop
```

end of error

```
2022-01-22 19:44:42 - blockimgdiff.py - INFO    : Finding transfers...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 2333, in <module>
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 2312, in main
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 2052, in GenerateNonAbOtaPackage
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 774, in WriteFullOTAPackage
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/ota_from_target_files.py", line 689, in GetBlockDifferences
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/common.py", line 2661, in __init__
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/blockimgdiff.py", line 342, in Compute
  File "/home/alexander/crDroid/out/host/linux-x86/bin/ota_from_target_files/blockimgdiff.py", line 1561, in FindTransfers
AssertionError
19:44:42 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (16:19 (mm:ss)) ####
```

As I understand the problem in the build.prop files. in those folders (where the error can not read) they are not. What should I do to create them?

Answer (score 0):

1. find the releasetools.py in your device tree
2. search for `android_info` add `.decode('UTF-8')` at the end of the line like this:

   ```
    android_info = input_zip.read("OTA/android-info.txt").decode('UTF-8')
   ```